# How to divide a data.frame into seversal data.frames according to some specail character?

Tags: r, dataframe

How to divide a data.frame into seversal data.frames according to some specail character?

```
df <- tibble(NumberA = c(5,3,2,0,"\\#",2,0,"\\#",3,1,1,3,1,0,"\\#"),
             NumberB = c(5,6,2,5,"\\#",4,3,"\\#",4,3,2,1,3,9,"\\#"))
```

[image]

[image: the new generated data.frames]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Option 1***

A `base` one-liner :

```
split(df, replace(cumsum(df$NumberA == "\\#"), df$NumberA == "\\#", NA))
```

---

***Option 2***

A `dplyr` solution with `group_split()`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(grp = cumsum(NumberA == "\\#")) %>%
  filter(NumberA != "\\#") %>%
  group_split(.keep = FALSE)
```

---

***Output***

```
# [[1]]
# # A tibble: 4 x 2
#   NumberA NumberB
#   <chr>   <chr>  
# 1 5       5      
# 2 3       6      
# 3 2       2      
# 4 0       5      
# 
# [[2]]
# # A tibble: 2 x 2
#   NumberA NumberB
#   <chr>   <chr>  
# 1 2       4      
# 2 0       3      
# 
# [[3]]
# # A tibble: 6 x 2
#   NumberA NumberB
#   <chr>   <chr>  
# 1 3       4      
# 2 1       3      
# 3 1       2      
# 4 3       1      
# 5 1       3      
# 6 0       9
```

---

***Update***

If you wanna get the mean of each column in each `data.frame` and combine all the means into one `data.frame`, you can use `map_dfr()` in `purrr`.

```
library(purrr)

map_dfr(df_split, ~ colMeans(mutate(.x, across(everything(), as.numeric))))

# # A tibble: 3 x 2
#   NumberA NumberB
#     <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1     2.5    4.5 
# 2     1      3.5 
# 3     1.5    3.67
```

where `df_split` is the splitted data.

Comment: thanks it is great, what if i wanna get the mean of each column of each data.frame? then combine all the means into one data.frame?

Answer (score 3):

A mix of `base R` and `tidyverse` would be (Altought @DarrenTsai solution is very optimal):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
#Data
df <- tibble(NumberA=c(5,3,2,0,"\\#",2,0,"\\#",3,1,1,3,1,0,"\\#"),
             NumberB=c(5,6,2,5,"\\#",4,3,"\\#",4,3,2,1,3,9,"\\#"))
#Detect characters
index <- which(df$NumberA=='\\#')
#Assign var
df$Var <- NA
df$Var[index]<-1:length(index)
#Fill
df %>% fill(Var,.direction = 'up') -> df1
#Remove rows with character
df1 <- df1[-index,]
#Compute mean
df1 %>% mutate(NumberA=as.numeric(NumberA),NumberB=as.numeric(NumberB)) %>%
  group_by(Var) %>% summarise_all(.funs = mean) %>% mutate(Var=paste0('df',Var)) -> dfmean
#Split
L1 <- split(df1,df1$Var)
#Remove var
L1 <- lapply(L1,function(x) {x$Var<-NULL; return(x)})
#Dataframes
names(L1)<-paste0('df',names(L1))
list2env(L1,envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

It will create:

```
df1
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  NumberA NumberB
  <chr>   <chr>  
1 5       5      
2 3       6      
3 2       2      
4 0       5   

df2
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  NumberA NumberB
  <chr>   <chr>  
1 2       4      
2 0       3  

df3
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  NumberA NumberB
  <chr>   <chr>  
1 3       4      
2 1       3      
3 1       2      
4 3       1      
5 1       3      
6 0       9
```

And for the means the output:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  Var   NumberA NumberB
  <chr>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1 df1       2.5    4.5 
2 df2       1      3.5 
3 df3       1.5    3.67
```

Comment: thank you, what if i wanna get the mean of each column of each data.frame? then combine all the means into one data.frame?

Comment: @AndyIan I have updated the solution with what you want :)

Answer (score 2):

I created the df again using the data.frame function, the functin tibble did not work for me.

But I created a list with the new df splited by our index "\#".

```
# Require packages
require(dplyr)

# Create the df
df <- data.frame(NumberA=c(5,3,2,0,"\\#",2,0,"\\#",3,1,1,3,1,0,"\\#"),
                 NumberB=c(5,6,2,5,"\\#",4,3,"\\#",4,3,2,1,3,9,"\\#"))


# Create a split point based on the special character, and filter to remains just the inter "special character lines".
df <- df %>% mutate(split_point = NumberA == "\\#",
                    block = with(rle(split_point), rep(seq_along(lengths), lengths))) %>%
    filter(split_point == F)

# Create an empty list to store the data frames inside a loop
list_df <- list()

# Unique blcks of df    
blokcs <- unique(df$block)


# Loop for create the list of data frames
for (i in 1:length(blokcs)) {
    list_df[[i]] <- df[df$block == blokcs[i], ]
}

list_df
```